# how to write curl command for getting data which updated in last 10 min

Tags: linux, url, curl

i have tried these two curl command but not getting correct response

```
 curl --request GET 'https://localhost:8080/api/alarms?sort-by=lastReceiveTime&from-date=date -d'now-10 minutes'' -H 'Authorization: Key demo-key

curl --request GET 'https://localhost:8080/api/alarms?sort-by=lastReceiveTime&from-date="'"$(date --utc +%FT%T.%3NZ) -d 'now-10 minutes'"'"' -H 'Authorization: Key demo-key'
```

this command gives all alarm ...but we want only those alarm which came in last 10 min.

Comment: "not getting correct response" isn't enough to go off of.  What is the response you are getting?  What response did you expect?  What are you querying against?

Comment: no ..these above both not gives correct response  ....these two showing all alarm which are present in web dashboard...Sort-by ,lastReceiveTime,from-date these are the parameter that already defined ...

Comment: i expecting ....the command will show all the alarm that just came in last 10 min .....and i want to know how to create api query ....is it right way to generate api query using curl command that i have written in question ...??